# Можно ли обработать два ListView в пределах одного activity на android?

Tags: android, listview

Делаю небольшое приложение, которое показывает несколько ListView через ViewFlipper. Для обработки кликов использую найденный на developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/listview.php код, прописав его отдельно для каждого компонента.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> eventAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, events);
        lstEvents.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
        lstGreetings.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
                display("for event " + position);
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> greetAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, greetings);
        lstGreetings.setAdapter(greetAdapter);
        lstGreetings.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
                display("for greet " + position);
            }
        });
```

к сожалению при этом обрабатывается клики лишь на последнем из списков. не могу понять как модифицировать код, чтобы корректно обрабатывались нажатия в каждом из списков. буду очень признателен за подсказки. оригинальный код обработки имеет вид

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,
      long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) itemClicked).getText(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: вы два раза вызываете `setOnItemClickListener` у `lstGreetings`, в первый раз надо `lstEvents`